# pyqt5 mediaplayer how to get if the video ended?

Tags: python, pyqt5, media

pyqt5 mediaplayer  how to get if the video ended? is there anything like == EndState or to make it loop

```
if media.state.end() == MediaPlayer.Endstate
    media.play()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if the *media* has reached the end, use the [`mediaStatusChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#mediaStatusChanged) signal:

```
        self.mediaPlayer.mediaStatusChanged.connect(self.statusChanged)

    def statusChanged(self, status):
        if status == QMediaPlayer.EndOfMedia:
            print('playback ended!')
```

If you want to loop it, instead, you should use a [QMediaPlaylist](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplaylist.html):

```
    self.playlist = QMediaPlaylist()
    self.playlist.addMedia(QMediaContent(...))
    self.playlist.setPlaybackMode(self.playlist.Loop)
    self.mediaPlayer.setPlaylist(self.playlist)
```

Note that the playlist object **must** be persistent; in this case, I made it an instance attribute, you might even create it with the media player as parent (`playlist = QMediaPlaylist(self.mediaPlayer)`). This is mandatory, otherwise the playlist will get garbage collected, resulting in the media player not playing anything since the playlist got deleted.